# Can't stop text gradient animation from resetting when complete

Tags: css, vue.js

I need to copy [this animation](https://dribbble.com/shots/3969194-Travel-Agency-Landing-Page) and I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to get the text to stay swiped out once the animation completes.
Here's my CSS code so far

```
.title{
    pointer-events: none;
    grid-area: 1/2/2/3;
    place-self: center;
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,
      rgba(255,255,255,1) 5%,
      rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background-size: 130%;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

@keyframes titleAnimationSequence{
    0% {
      background-position-x: 50%;
    }
    100% {
      background-position-x: -700%;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }

  .titleAnimation-enter-active{
    animation: titleAnimationSequence .3s ease-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

My Vue template looks like this

```
<template>
    <!--stuff-->
    <h1 v-if="!plusButtonComplete" class="title align-middle sm:text-[length:var(--text-ultraJumbotron-2)] md:text-[length:var(--text-ultraJumbotron-3)] z-30">
        Explore
      </h1>
      <Transition name="titleAnimation">
        <h1 v-if="plusButtonComplete" class="title align-middle sm:text-[length:var(--text-ultraJumbotron-2)] md:text-[length:var(--text-ultraJumbotron-3)]">
            Explore
        </h1>
      </Transition>
    <!-- more stuff -->
</template>
```

I figured the `animation-fill-mode: forwards` part would stop it from resetting but it just goes back to its initial state one the animation completes.  How do I stop this from happening until I want to toggle it back?

Comment: you should try `animation-fill-mode` https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: I did, its even in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `animation-fill-mode: forwards` would retain the style values that are set by the last keyframe. But when you use the vue `Transition` component, the class `titleAnimation-enter-active` is:

> Applied during the entire entering phase. Added before the element is inserted, **removed when the transition/animation finishes**

See the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#css-based-transitions)

When the class is removed, all CSS properties (including animation) will be removed from the element. So your style will not be applied.

#### Solution

- Add all desired styles to your element class (`.title`), **NOT** the transition active class
- Add animation styles to transition classes

##### Solution 1: Use CSS transition

```js
const {
  createApp,
  ref
} = Vue

createApp({
  setup() {
    const showHero = ref(false)
    return {
      showHero
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
.hero {
  padding: 3em 5em;
  border: solid 1px black;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 3s transform;
  will-change: transform;
}

h1 {
  color: green;
  font-size: 5em;
}


/* for entering animation */

.hero-enter-from {
  transform: scale(0);
}


/* for leaving animation */

.hero-leave-to {
  transform: scale(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="showHero = !showHero">Toggle</button>
  <Transition name="hero">
    <div class="hero" v-if="showHero">
      <h1>I'm growing</h1>
    </div>
  </Transition>
</div>
```

##### Solution 2: Use CSS animation

```js
const {
  createApp,
  ref
} = Vue

createApp({
  setup() {
    const showHero = ref(false)
    return {
      showHero
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
.hero {
  padding: 3em 5em;
  border: solid 1px black;
  text-align: center;
  will-change: transform;
}

h1 {
  color: green;
  font-size: 5em;
}


/* for entering animation */

.hero-enter-active {
  animation: upScale 3s;
}


/* for leaving animation */

.hero-leave-active {
  animation: downScale 3s;
}

@keyframes upScale {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes downScale {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="showHero = !showHero">Toggle</button>
  <Transition name="hero">
    <div class="hero" v-if="showHero">
      <h1>I'm growing</h1>
    </div>
  </Transition>
</div>
```

Comment: ok I'm trying the second option and I'm still having the same issue with the animation going back to the default state.

Comment: @Optiq Can you share what did you try?